# Any patterns for managing typescript package dependencies with bower?

Tags: typescript, bower, amd

### What works

I have been building modules into a single outFile with a declaration file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outFile": "built/index.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "bower_components",
        "built"
    ]
}
```

When setting up the dependent project I can import via bower and typings:

```
>bower install git://github.com/ca0v/ol3-symbolizer.git#v3.20.1 --save
>typings install ol3-symbolizer=github:ca0v/ol3-symbolizer/built/index.d.ts#v3.20.1 --save --global
```

And list the dependency in the AMD "dep" array:

```
deps: [
    "https://rawgit.com/ca0v/ol3-symbolizer/v3.20.1/built/index.js",
    "https://rawgit.com/ca0v/ol3-layerswitcher/v3.20.1/built/index.js",
    "https://rawgit.com/ca0v/ol3-popup/v3.20.1/built/index.js",
    "built/index"
],
```

### Now to my question.

I'd rather not use add the `deps` nor use `typings` at all, but instead reference the dependency:

```
import Symbolizer = require("../../bower_components/ol3-symbolizer/format/ags-symbolizer");
```

This works fine when there are no nested dependencies.  But in this case ol3-symbolizer also has a bower dependency on ol3-popup.  Using `bower` to install `ol3-symbolizer` also installs `ol3-popup` but flattens the file structure and the references break:

```
import { Popup } from "../bower_components/ol3-popup/src/ol3-popup";
```

Need to be fixed and would become:

```
import { Popup } from "../../ol3-popup/src/ol3-popup";
```

Is there a way of organizing these projects in such as way that avoids breaking these paths?

Comment: see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add paths use tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es3",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile": "./built/index.js",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "ol3-layerswitcher/*": [
                "./bower_components/ol3-layerswitcher/ol3-layerswitcher/*"
            ],
            "ol3-symbolizer/*": [
                "./bower_components/ol3-symbolizer/ol3-symbolizer/*"
            ],
            "ol3-popup/*": [
                "./bower_components/ol3-popup/ol3-popup/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "bower_components",
        "built",
        "ol3-lab/tests/data/routes",
        "ol3-lab/tests/routing.ts"
    ]
}
```

With this change, all references to bower dependencies can be codes as if they were in the root directory and the result is all dependencies are combined into a single output file.